# drawing over canvas but image is getting disappeared in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a canvas in HTML5. If I use a canvas (with fileList as id) it is not getting displayed on the screen but if I used a div it is getting displayed. I want to display a rectangle over an image for annotation
Whenever I am clicking the rectangle the image is getting disppeared.I want the image to stay and the rectangle to be drawn over it.

```js
 var arr;
        var index = 0;
        var length = 0;
        window.onload = function () {
            window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
                fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
                fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");
            canvas = document.getElementById('fileList');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                if (fileElem) {
                    fileElem.click();
                }
                e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
            }, false);
        }
        function handleFiles(files) {
            if (!files.length) {
                fileList.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
            } else {
                length = files.length;
                arr = new Array(length);
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    arr[i] = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
                }
                drawImage(arr[0]);
            }
        }
        function drawImage(url) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('fileList');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = url;
            imageObj.id = "dispimg";
            imageObj.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 50, 400, 400);
            }
        }

        function leftaction() {
            if (length == 0) {
                alert("select files");
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (index > 0) {
                    drawImage(arr[--index]);
                }
                else {
                    index = 0;
                    drawImage(arr[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        var rect = {};
        var drag = false;
        function init() {

            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
        }

        function mouseDown(e) {
            rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            drag = true;
        }

        function mouseUp() { drag = false; }

        function mouseMove(e) {
            if (drag) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

                rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
                rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
                ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
            }
        }
        function rightaction() {
            if (length == 0) {
                alert("select files");
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (index < length - 1) {
                    drawImage(arr[++index]);
                }
                else {
                    index = length - 1;
                    drawImage(arr[index]);

                }
            }
        }
        function zoomin() {
            var myImg = document.getElementById("dispimg");
            var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
            var curheight = myImg.clientHeight;
            if (currWidth == 600 && curheight == 600) {
                alert("Maximum zoom-in level reached.");
            } else {
                myImg.style.width = (currWidth + 50) + "px";
                myImg.style.height = (curheight + 50) + "px";
            }
        }
        function zoomout() {
            var myImg = document.getElementById("dispimg");
            var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
            var curheight = myImg.clientHeight;
            if (currWidth == 100 && curheight == 100) {
                alert("Maximum zoom-out level reached.");
            } else {
                myImg.style.width = (currWidth - 50) + "px";
                myImg.style.height = (curheight - 50) + "px";
            }
        }
        function resize() {
            var myImg = document.getElementById("dispimg");
            var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
            var curheight = myImg.clientHeight;
            if (curheight != 400 && currWidth != 400) {
                myImg.style.width = 300 + "px";
                myImg.style.height = 300 + "px";
            }
            else
                alert("Image is orignal sized");
        }
```

```css
.card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;

        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 8px 16px;
        }

        a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .main3 {
            background-color: black;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
        }

        #navigation {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .card1 {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .card2 {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 200px;
            height: 250px;
            margin: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .square {
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .main {
            border: none;
            margin: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .main1 {
            border: none;
            margin: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .point {
            border: none;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .shape-head {
            border: none;
            outline: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            background-color: grey;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px;
            padding-top: 12px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: black;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .button1 {
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        .button1:hover {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        #my-file {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #container {
            padding: 2px 16px;
        }

        #my_file {
            display: none;
        }

        .side-disp {
            float: left;
        }

        #fileList {
            height: 680px;
            width: 800px;
            border: black solid;
            display: flex;
            background: none;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            float: left;
        }

        ul.region_shape {
            font-size: xx-large;
            list-style-type: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0.4em 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        ul.region_shape li {
            float: left;
            padding: 0 0.2em;
            fill: #ffffff;
            stroke: #000000;
        }

        ul.region_shape li:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            fill: #ffffff;
            stroke: #ff0000;
        }

        #get_file {
            background: grey;
            border: 5px solid grey;
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .rectangle {
            border: 10px solid black;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: black;
            z-index: 3;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <symbol id="shape_rectangle">
                <title>Rectangular region shape</title>
                <rect width="20" height="12" x="6" y="10" stroke-width="2" />
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="shape_circle">
                <title>Circular region shape</title>
                <circle r="10" cx="16" cy="16" stroke-width="2" />
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="shape_ellipse">
                <title>Elliptical region shape</title>
                <ellipse rx="12" ry="8" cx="16" cy="16" stroke-width="2" />
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="shape_polygon">
                <title>Polyline region shape</title>
                <path d="M 15.25,2.2372 3.625,11.6122 6,29.9872 l 20.75,-9.625 2.375,-14.75 z" stroke-width="2" />
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="shape_point">
                <title>Point region shape</title>
                <circle r="3" cx="16" cy="16" stroke-width="2" />
            </symbol>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%">
        <div class="side-disp">
            <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
            <button class=" button button1" id="fileSelect">Load Files</button>
            <div class="card">
                <span class="shape-head">SHAPES</span>
                <ul class="region_shape">
                    <li id="region_shape_rect" onclick="init()" title="Rectangle">
                        <svg height="32" viewbox="0 0 32 32">
                            <use xlink:href="#shape_rectangle"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </li>
                    <li id="region_shape_ellipse" title="Ellipse">
                        <svg height="32" viewbox="0 0 32 32">
                            <use xlink:href="#shape_ellipse"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </li>
                    <li id="region_shape_polygon" title="Polygon">
                        <svg height="32" viewbox="0 0 32 32">
                            <use xlink:href="#shape_polygon"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </li>
                    <li id="region_shape_point" title="Point">
                        <svg height="32" viewbox="0 0 32 32">
                            <use xlink:href="#shape_point"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card1">
                <span class="shape-head">TOOLS</span>
                <img src="plus.svg" alt="" height="30px" width="30px" class="main1" onclick="zoomin()" draggable="false">
                <img src="minus.svg" alt="" height="30px" width="30px" class="main1" onclick="zoomout()" draggable="false">
                <img src="resize.png" alt="" height="30px" width="30px" class="main1" onclick="resize()" draggable="false">
            </div>
            <div class="card2">
                <span class="shape-head">TAGS</span>
                <button class="button button1">TAG1</button>
                <button class="button button1">TAG2</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <canvas id="fileList" height="680px" width="800px"></canvas>
        <div id="navigation" align=right>
            <button class="main3" onclick="leftaction()">&#8249;</button>
            <button class="main3" onclick="rightaction()">&#8250;</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```